# Input type submit won't round

Tags: html, css

I tried to make button rounded:

```css
.btn-rounded {
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Posalji" class="btn-rounded">
```

But it won't make it round!

Comment: Works fine here in a code snippet, shows rounded corners.

Comment: Where are you putting your styles? Do you see them being overridden in the browser's inspector?

Comment: Fixed it. The problem was that I had to put that css at the top. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

The code is fine. You should always load the CSS before loading the code. So, put CSS at the top in `<head>`